# Determination of Calcium from a mixture of calcium and magnesium using Back Titration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

I've some confusions in the experiment. Step 7 gives us the concentration of both calcium and magnesium (Ca+Mg combined), right? How do we find the concentration of magnesium only from back titration described in the next steps?
Can someone please explain.[image: Please see the experiment described in the picture attached]

Comment: What is the meaning of the end of step $3$ ? Namely, I repeat : dissolving $0.2$ g of ErioT in $15$ mL of triethanolamine and $5$ mL of absolute ethanol or in $20$ mL of the latter ? What is the meaning of this "or $20$ mL of the latter" ? Should I use $5$ or $20$ mL ethanol ?

Comment: @Maurice This step just describes the preparation of indicator solution which can be prepared either by dissolving 0.2g of EBT in a mixture (15mL triethanolamine + 5mL absolute ethanol) or by dissolving 0.2g EBT in 20mL of Ethanol only.

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts. 
// Optional: Formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Answer (score 1):

The general reactions are described very well here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Laboratory_Experiments/Wet_Lab_Experiments/General_Chemistry_Labs/General_Chemistry_Labs/Complexometric_Calcium_Determination_(Experiment)

Ca++ and Mg++ both form complexes with EDTA, Ca++EDTA and Mg++EDTA. The Ca++ complex is the stronger so Mg++ will not destroy the Ca++ complex. Both ions form complexes with the Eriochrome. Here the Mg++ complex is stronger and the Ca++ complex relatively weak such that the end point with Ca++ is vague and the end point with Mg++ is sharper. Both complexes with the indicator are red. When the indicator complexes are destroyed by EDTA excess the indicator is blue. Titration of the sample to the blue endpoint gives an approximate Ca++ amount, record this value. Add the excess EDTA and record the total volume exactly. The solution should be blue. All the calcium is complexed to the EDTA. Titrate the solution with the Mg++ standard. This converts the excess EDTA into the Mg++EDTA complex. As the end point is neared be careful. When the blue color fades all the EDTA is the Ca++ and Mg++ complexes. Record the volume. The total EDTA solution is their sum. The difference is the calcium.

The procedure should be more explicit in recording data.